# Dreamweaver and Binary PUT via FTP

Tags: ftp, dreamweaver, zend-guard

As we all know (don't we?), the **FTP functionality on Dreamweaver is inexcusable** for a professional product, but I bear with it because Dreamweaver has other useful stuff that overshadows the FTP.

However, I have a specific FTP situation which has been annoying me for a few years now, and was hoping someone had a solution.

We use the **ZEND encryption** on some PHP files. Once you do that, the files are no longer text file (but instead, binary files).

My understanding is that Dreamweaver FTPs everything as binary (maybe I misunderstand?), but each time I upload (FTP) those ZEND-encrypted PHP files to a server using Dreamweaver, they do not work (just a white screen -- meaning they are corrupt).

I have to drop into the command-line FTP, FTP into the server, and manually PUT the files (after typing BIN of course). Not too hard, but adds extra steps I would rather avoid.

Is there any adjustment, tool, add-on, or ANYTHING that will force Dreamweaver to upload the files correctly?

Comment: Dreamweaver doesn't send everything binary - it has an option kicking around somewhere where it auto-selects which method to use. You can force it on or off dependant on certain file types, I believe - but I'm not positive how. You'll have to check out the documentation or browse the menus :)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have to modify your `FTPExtensionMap.txt`, that's what Dreamweaver uses to select the FTP transfer mode.

Although that would make *all* `.php` files to be transferred in BINARY, which may not be what you want if you're transferring back & forth between Win/UNIX/Mac other non-encoded `.php` files

[Here the instructions on how to modify the file](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Dreamweaver/10.0_Extending/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d117f53d6108-7fcc.html).

Comment: Tried it - didn't work (although according to documentation, it should). When I say 'didn't work', I mean that file still renders white screen.